# How to get a HTML page using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I know you may think this question is stupid, but I need to use HtmlUnit. However, it returns a page either as XML or as text.

I don't how to get the pure HTML (the same as the source code that browsers return)

I need this, because I need to use some written modules. Any ideas?

Comment: mr. Vai asks if you can "provide fullcode which extracts webpage using HTMLUNIT"

Comment: I have save problem , Can u help me ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781322/java-program-to-read-a-html-page-and-save-its-content-use-javascript

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to achieve your goal:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Page page = webClient.getPage("http://example.com");
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
String content = response.getContentAsString();
```

See [javadocs of the WebResponse.html#getContentAsString() method](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html#getContentAsString%28%29).

Comment: Thanks! :) I found it just before seeing your comment!

Comment: but there is a problem, it doesn't show the texts in <nonscript> tags!

Comment: webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) - Add this