# How to send a request with inetAddress in HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, httprequest, htmlunit, http-request-parameters

I can send a Http GET request by `InetAddress` like above.

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName(interfaceIp));
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);  
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUrl);
response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

But I want to try it via `HtmlUnit`. Is there a way for that?

**Edit:**

I try this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(baseurl);
page.getTitleText();
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354099/how-to-get-a-html-page-using-htmlunit

Comment: thank you, but i don't try this, I have to send request with a spesific Interface ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(interfaceIp);
webClient.getOptions().setLocalAddress(inetAddress);
```

Comment: I use htmlUnit 2.23 version and i got an error -> there is no setLocalAddress option

Comment: Thank you so much, it's OK!.